# Name conflict error while performing this copying loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm simply trying to transfer over the first 17 sheets in a masterworkbook into a new workbook, but I keep getting various naming conflict errors on certain sheets. This results into a ton of Yes clicks (near 100) before I can move onto the next sheet transfer. I did research and attempted deleting the error sheets out of the name manager to no avail.

Code for my loop:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wbkTarget As Workbook
Dim i As Long
Set wbkTarget = Workbooks.Add()
With ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = Nothing
    For i = 1 To 17
        Set wks = .Worksheets(i)
        wks.Copy wbkTarget.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Next i
End With
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: The target workbook already includes the name in question... but I think you can use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to handle this.

Comment: @bigben I figured that would work fine, and I have that set in another module that flows into this, but I wanted to make sure that I wasn't ignoring something important by slapping that line of code before the loop